Announcement: A stacks project for category theory
I'm releasing today The Clowder Project, a tag-based wiki and reference for category theory powered by Gerby.
I plan to eventually make it into a comprehensive resource for category theory, in the same way that the Stacks Project is a comprehensive resource for algebraic geometry.
As of writing, it consists of 578 pages, with around 4000 more pages of material on category theory being slowly polished and converted into a form that works with Gerby. There are also 6000 more pages of material on other subjects which might eventually also make their way into it, as they either serve as either illustrating examples or stepping stones.
Here are some links:

The website: https://clowderproject.com
The GitHub project with the source files: link
Everything currently released in PDF form: link
The Discord server for the project, for discussions and updates: link


(PS: I hope this post is on-topic, as although it's not specifically on topics surrounding MathOverflow, it's probably still of interest to the MathOverflow community.)

I will just add that the project is mentioned here, too: Online, evolving, collaborative foundational text projects.

Hmm. Something like this might be useful as a "standard resource" to point to, either for people to check for "basic" questions, or as something people writing answers might like to point to, as a contrast to the nLab (which is a recommended resource, but clearly rather idiosyncratic, compared to a general CT encyclopedia like your project).
